# storage.googleapis.com malware on chromium

Tags: security, chromium, malware

I did a serious mistake of opening the following malware link on my chromium browser:

hover here below to show probably dangerous link

> https ://storage.googleapis.[com]/cerejunulojohedagukaru/fugenidihovevasezulisovele?Crbdxgo9hUBae

I wish to know what are the implications, on the OS as well as on the browser.
p.s. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I think the better question would be is to let us know what malware you got on your system and how we can help you clean it up, instead of having people infect their own systems by going to the link.

Comment: I added `[ ]` around `com` so one cannot open the link by accident

Comment: @Terrance I don't really know what malware i got on my system. I would be grateful if you could tell me some way to know that.

Comment: If you have `clamav` installed you can scan your entire computer with `sudo clamscan -vr /` and maybe that might help identify it.

Comment: I tried it out, it's just a redirector (it sent me to fake dating websites and Alibaba). As long as you didn't download or install anything, you'll most likely be fine.